# ready state problem with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have the following problem. I'm trying to load a set of tab loading dinamically with jQuery.
When I get the new contents (via POST) the tabs() function abort and don't build the
tabs. I'm using this functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var array_with_alias_id = $.getJSON("/getAliasForMatchAll/", null,
        function (data){
            array = data.aliases_id;
            load(array);
        });
    $("#next_left").click(function(){next_left()});

    //load(array_with_alias_id);
});



function next_left(){
    if(j >= array.length-1){
        var l = j
    } else {
        var l = j+=1;
    }
    $("#alias_id_left").val(list_left[l]);
    $("#merge_alias_id_left").val(list_left[l]);
    $.post("/visor/",{"alias_id":list_left[l],"position":"L"},
            function(data){
                $("#tabsL").html(data).ready(function(){
                    $("#tabsL").tabs();
                });
            });
}
```

I think that my problem is an ajax problem and i have read this [0], 
but i can't give with the solution.
The function next_left() it works only one time. I think that the document for 
this function is ready, but when i load the tabs it doesnt work 
(i think that tab call the method abort, because if i see the html with firebug 
it change, but not all).

Any clue?

[0]http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:AJAX_and_Events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People on IRC helped me.
I have now changed the function after the .POST to this:

```
function next_left(){
    if(j >= array.length-1) {
        var l = j
    } 

    else {
        var l = j+=1;
    }

    $("#alias_id_left").val(list_left[l]);
    $("#merge_alias_id_left").val(list_left[l]);
    $.post("/visor/",{"alias_id":list_left[l],"position":"L"},

    function(data) {
        $("#tabsL").html(data).tabs("destroy").tabs();                
    });
}
```

They correctly advised me that the ready function applies to the document and does not work how I used it. I hope the fixed code I posted here aids others.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing  **$("#next_left").click(function(){next_left()});** with:

```
$("#next_left").live('click', function(){next_left()});
```

Comment: Thanks Nick G, but it does not work :-(
Any other tip, please.